# contracts/3_Ballot.sol:33:37: TypeError: Named argument does not match function declaration

Tags: solidity

from solidity:
contracts/3_Ballot.sol:33:37: TypeError: Named argument does not match function declaration.
Request memory newRequest = Request({
^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

I get this error every time. What should i do for the solve it?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Campaign {

    struct Request  {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address recipient;
        bool complete;
    }

    Request[] public requests;
    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContirbution;
    address[] public approvers;

    modifier restricted() {
        require (msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function Campaign (uint minimum) public {
        manager = msg.sender;
        minimumContirbution = minimum;
    }

    function contribute () public payable {
        require(msg.value > minimumContirbution);
        approvers.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) restricted public  {
        Request memory newRequest = Request({ 
            description: description,
            value: value,
            restricted: restricted,
            complete: false
        });

        requests.push(newRequest);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `Request struct` in this way and push it into `requests` array:

```
function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) restricted public {
    Request memory newRequest = Request(description, value, recipient, false);
    requests.push(newRequest);
}
```

In this way, you can add the struct into your array and can retrieve with all parameters setted previously.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're are using wrong argument(restricted) inside you Request type

try this:

```
  Request memory newRequest = Request({
        descritption: descritpion,
        value: value,
        recipient: recipient,
        complete: false
    });
```